# Bug in Div height IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout

Hihi,

I´m slicing down the main layout for a webpage.
For some reason the div id="main" won´t align to the header

url: http://nicejob.is/clients/pizzahollin/www/forsida.htm

As you can see the div id="main" (in green) match perfectly with the header
in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the "main" goes almost overlap the header

I´ve done this many times before without this bug so I don´t know what ghost
is hunting me now

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Which version(s!) of IE are you asking about? IE8?

Comment: hi, yes I´m viewing it in IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `display:block;` on the `<header>`